# how to get modified csv file while TestNG test suite is in progress

Tags: csv, selenium, testng

I am running a test suite in which testNG.xml looks like below:

```
<suite>
<test name="createFlow">
    <classes>
        <class name="createReservation">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="modifyFlow">
    <classes>
        <class name="modifyReservation">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

The parameters for creating the reservation are being taken from a reservation.csv. Once reservation gets created, reservation ID is stored in that csv,ie. it overrides the value of ID already present there, which is used for modifying that particular reservation, code of which is written in modifyReservation.java.

The problem i am facing is once i run the test suite, the modify flow doesn't fetch the recent reservation ID which is just created in reservation flow from csv, but it takes the ID which was earlier mentioned in the csv.

Please suggest what changes should i make so that in same suite, during the execution is going on, i am able to fetch the updated IDs.

Comment: Try save and close file after updating ID, and reopen file before fetching ID.

Comment: I am already doing that. I am closing the bufferedReader and bufferWriter after every test case, which reopens in next test case.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the file, you have read and write methods for reading/writing data in the csv file, use local variables in every method instead of global variables.
Create new object of FileInputStream and FileOutputStream in each and every method.
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(csvFilePath);
Hope it will work

Comment: I have below code in place already.
While reading from csv file, i am starting with below code:
`CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     csv.openStream(), "UTF-8")));`
While writing into csv file, i am starting with below code:
`br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));`

Creating new variables for each are of no help currently.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect reason why databases were developed.

> 1. Create a new MongoDB or MySQL DB first.
> 2. Then create tables and columns based on your data needs.
> 3. Write a select query to get data from those tables.

You will avoid all sorts of permissions, locking, refresh etc issues by using databases.